# High Charts - Organizational Chart

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I want to use the high charts organizational chart but could not remove the top level parent "shareholders". The test chart looks like:

[image]

The example at [high charts](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/organization-chart) has a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/organization-chart).

I tried to remove share holders from the link series:

```
    series: [{
    type: 'organization',
    name: 'Highsoft',
    keys: ['from', 'to'],
    data: [
        ['Shareholders', 'Board'], // deleted this line
        ['Board', 'CEO'],
        ['CEO', 'CTO'],
        ['CEO', 'CPO'],
        ['CEO', 'CSO'],
        ['CEO', 'HR'],
        ['CTO', 'Product'],
        ['CTO', 'Web'],
        ['CSO', 'Sales'],
        ['HR', 'Market'],
        ['CSO', 'Market'],
        ['HR', 'Market'],
        ['CTO', 'Market']
    ],
```

And also deleted shareholders from nodes:

```
        }],
    nodes: [{
        id: 'Shareholders' // deleted this line and { } above/below
    }, {
        id: 'Board'
    }, {
```

But then the chart didn't render at all. How do I remove shareholders?

Answer (score 2):

Since you removed the data `Shareholders`, you might want to change the column for `Market`

```
{
      id: 'Market',
      name: 'Marketing team',
      column: 4
    }
```

Working Example:

https://codepen.io/johnsonsamuel/pen/WNRVdRB

Comment: Why do I need to change column for Market? And I see you left the shareholders node in there, but it is not drawn?

Comment: Since you had removed the one level, which is Shareholders. If you see there are 5 levels before removing the Shareholders, once you remove it becomes 4 but the column refers to 5. Hope this helps.

Comment: So data array defines lines, levels defines the levels, but nodes I would think defines whats drawn, yet you left shareholders node in? What defines the level of a node since nodes dont refer to levels?

Comment: I just removed shareholders from nodes and it works. If I am correct, nodes are used to have image or description or title if the data is matched with the id.